# Check if Backend User belongs to Group with OctoberCMS Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com) based on Laravel.

I have a backend user, `Matt` in Groups `owners`, `administrators`.

How do I check if user belongs to a specific group to allow authentication?

I was told I need to pass a Group Object, but I don't know what that is.

```
use Auth;
use BackendAuth;
use Backend\Models\User;

if (BackendAuth::check()) {

    // get current backend user
    $backend_user = BackendAuth::getUser();

    // get current backend user's groups
    $backend_user_groups = Backend::getUser()->groups;

    // authenticate
    if ($backend_user->inGroup('administrators') {

    }
}
```

Error

```
public function inGroup($group)
Call to a member function getKey() on string
```

Another way I've tried

```
if (User::inGroup('administrators') {

}
```

Error

`Non-static method October\Rain\Auth\Models\User::inGroup() should not be called statically`

Docs

https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/users

https://github.com/octobercms/library/blob/master/src/Auth/Models/User.php

Comment: Is there a reason you are checking for a group not a permission?

Comment: @dragontree In OctoberCMS I made backend user groups that have a set of permissions. I add a user to administrators or moderators, then in php check the current user's groups to allow access to a feature. Should I be doing it a different way?

Comment: You should use the `hasAccess` or `hasPermission()` functions for that.
Its documented here: https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/users#features

Comment: I'm using the authentication group on a custom component I made, I'm not sure if I know how to set up the permissions for the component.

Comment: the `registerPermissions()` function example is given on the same page of the documentation. After you register the permissions like that, they wil be shown in the backend groups page where you can then add or remove the from the groups or users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There could be some helper functions for this but you can also use this:

```
$backend_user->groups()->whereName('administrators')->exists();
```

Comment: I think it may be working, I'm doing some testing and I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: This works for detecting the group. I will have to do the permissions next, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also extend the backend user model and add a helper method to it to check roles. Do the following in the `boot()` method of your plugin:

```
use Backend\Models\User as BackendUser;

public function boot()
{
    BackendUser::extend(function($model) {

        $model->addDynamicMethod('hasRole', function($role) use ($model) {
            return $model->groups()->whereName($role)->exists();
        });

        $model->addDynamicMethod('isAdmin', function() use ($model) {
            return $model->hasRole('administrators');
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think first you should try to understand the errors before doing the `permissions part`

> public function inGroup($group)
>
> Call to a member function getKey() on string

Did you look what does the `inGroup()` function do ? This method does not expect a string as a parameter

Here's the complete function :

```
 /**
 * See if the user is in the given group.
 * @param Group $group
 * @return bool
 */
public function inGroup($group)
{
    foreach ($this->getGroups() as $_group) {
        if ($_group->getKey() == $group->getKey()) <<== Call to a member function getKey() on string
        { 
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

As regards the second error

> Non-static method October\Rain\Auth\Models\User::inGroup() should not be called statically

You should initialize non-static methods like this :

```
(new User)->someMethod()
```